# Convert SHP to GPX with predefined SHP style in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, style, gpx

I had defined graduated style in QGIS for points contained in shp format. I had saved this style in sld and qpj format so now I am able to open shp in QGIS and it automatically loads its style (I am not sure if it would with other GIS software assuming I have sld).

But what I would like to do is to convert/save/export this shp with defined style to gpx, kml or kmz (preferably to gpx).

I have been trying...

- Right click on a layer
- Save as...
- In Save vector layer as...: Format: GPX, Choose File Name, Symbology export: Feature Symbology (and Symbol Layer Symbology), GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES, FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES + other default options.

...but I havent had any luck.

Can this be done?

My goal is to upload gpx to Google My maps.

Answer (score 1):

In your shapefile add a field named `name` and another named `sym`. Both should be string. In the first you fill with the name of the point. And in the  second you should choose one of the **predefined symbols**. Here you can find a list of those symbols: https://gist.github.com/tonymorris/8778137 . Finally you export as GPX selecting those two fields and `GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES`. This way worked for me (QGIS 3.10 and Garmin 64st) I hope it works for you too.