# Populate new column using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS.

I have a layer that shows the conservation areas (CA in England and Wales. In this layer's attribute table I need to create a new column titled **Locale**. This column will show whether the CA is in Wales or England. I can't do this manually as there are a few thousand rows.

I am using a XYZ base map and have tried doing a spatial join, but cannot select this map.
I have added a layer that shows the country boundaries. From here I exported each country as a separate layer as I was planning on using the clip function to separate the features. I was then going to add the column and do something along the lines of '=Wales' for the whole column?

I am not very familiar with QGIS, I have tried spatial joins, and I have also tried using the field calculator. No dice.

Any ideas?

Comment: Run an overlay (e.g. union) which will cut the counties into your conservation areas and add the two layer's fields together.  For area fields you need to recalculate them in the union layers.

Comment: Statements of urgency generate downvotes and delays, not quick responses.

Comment: Add a sample of your data or, at least, some screenshot of your table.

Comment: You cant spatial join using a XYZ map, you need a vector dataset.

Comment: Or select the areas manually and add the attribute like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201024/updating-text-column-of-selected-features-in-qgis

Answer (score 0):

You can use the algorithm `native:joinattributesbylocation`. It's available in the Vector->Data management menu or via the processing tools widget by searching by name.

In the dialog choose your conservation area layer as the first, the borders dataset as the second layer and choose to add the country name field from your borders dataset.

This will create a new temporary layer with the country field added. From there you can then create your "Locale" field with the field calculator. Select the conservation areas layer, open the field calculator, choose "create new field", as expression choose the country name field from the "fields and values" catogory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method with "select by location" and the field calculator.

First select one feature from the borders dataset, e.g. Wales.

Then do "select by location" to select objects from the conservation area dataset that overlap with the selected features from the borders dataset.

Then click (to select) the conservation area layer in the layer tree and open the field calculator, choose "update only selected objects" and "create new field". Name the new field `locales`. As expression input `'Wales'` with the quotes. Run. Now all your conservation areas in Wales should have the locale.

Repeat for England, but that time in the field calculator choose "update existing field" and choose the locales field in the dropdown.